# I have a question while studying the example of mpi send and recv function

Tags: c, ubuntu, mpi

The code below shows an example of pingpong while studying the send and response function.
But I don't understand from the parter_rank .

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
const int PING_PONG_LIMIT = 10;

// Initialize the MPI environment
MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);
// Find out rank, size
int world_rank;
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_rank);
int world_size;
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);
 
// We are assuming 2 processes for this task
if (world_size != 2) {
fprintf(stderr, "World size must be two for %s\n", argv[0]);
MPI_Abort(MPI_COMM_WORLD, 1);
}

int ping_pong_count = 0;
int partner_rank = (world_rank + 1) % 2;
while (ping_pong_count < PING_PONG_LIMIT) {
  if (world_rank == ping_pong_count % 2) {
  // Increment the ping pong count before you send it
  ping_pong_count++;
  MPI_Send(&ping_pong_count, 1, MPI_INT, partner_rank, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  printf("%d sent and incremented ping_pong_count %d to %d\n", world_rank, ping_pong_count, partner_rank);
  } else {
  MPI_Recv(&ping_pong_count, 1, MPI_INT, partner_rank, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD,
           MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
  printf("%d received ping_pong_count %d from %d\n", 
         world_rank, ping_pong_count, partner_rank);}
  }
  MPI_Finalize();
}
```

Q1. Clearly, MPI_Comm_rank above defines it as world_rank, but I don't understand what partner_rank below means.
What is the difference between the two ranks?

Q2.When I don't understand  `if (world_rank == ping_pong_count % 2)`
Can't we just write "rank ==0" and "rank ==1"? Why did you put an arithmetic operator in there?

I'd appreciate your comment.

Comment: if you do not `if (world_rank == ping_pong_count %2)` your program (as currently written) would do a ping-ping instead of a ping-pong. as a matter of style, I think this program is a bit convoluted, but could be easily adapted to run on any even number of MPI tasks.

Comment: First count = 0, and so if (world_rank=(pingpong_count+1)%2) becomes world_rank=0. Does that partner_rank become 1?

Comment: `partner_rank` is a constant: `0`'s partner is `1` and `1`'s partner is `0`. In order to do a pingpong, rank 0 has to send,recv,send,recv, ..., and rank 1 has to recv,send,recv,send, ... That's the rationale for that `if`

Comment: thank you for your comment, may i ask one more? How do I implement this code without a partner_rank? When we removed the parter_rank and ran the parameter that included the parter_rank, only rank=0 sent the message and the program did not finish properly.

Comment: my advice is do not do that. but if you really want to, you will need to *unroll* your loop, e.g. `if (rank == 0) { MPI_Send(); MPI_Recv();} else {MPI_Recv(); MPI_Send();}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this seemingly unnecessary arithmetic and the introduction of additional rank variables is **code symmetry**. That is, since the most common type of MPI programs is one which runs as **multiple copies** of the **same program**, symmetric code means code that doesn't have conditional statements comparing the rank to specific constants. Why is this important? Because it makes code more flexible and easier to understand.

Compare the following two equivalent specifications of what a two-rank MPI ping-pong program looks like:

#### Specification 1

- rank 0 sends a message to rank 1
- rank 1 then sends the message back to rank 0
- the process repeats N times

An implementation of this specification in C-like pseudocode could be:

```
loop N times {
   if (rank == 0) {
      MPI_Send to 1
      MPI_Recv from 1
   }
   else if (rank == 1) {
      MPI_Recv from 0
      MPI_Send to 0
   }
}
```

#### Specification 2

- each rank receives from the other rank
- each rank then sends to the other rank
- the process repeats N-1 times
- in addition, rank 0 kickstarts the process by sending to the other rank and ends the process by receiving one last message from the other rank

A possible implementation in pseudocode:

```
other_rank = 1 - rank

if (rank == 0) {
   MPI_Send to other_rank
}

loop N-1 times {
   MPI_Recv from other_rank
   MPI_Send to other_rank
}

if (rank == 0) {
   MPI_Recv from other_rank
}
```

The second specification (and its implementation) may look more complex at first sight, but it isn't. It has the advantage that it is local - it doesn't give a global prescription of what specific ranks have to do. Instead, it gives a prescription of what any rank in the system does, only breaking the symmetry at the beginning and at the end of the process because something has to kickstart the chain.

What if we want to extend the system and have not two, but three ranks passing messages in a ring. We want rank 0 to pass a message to rank 1, which then passes it to rank 2, which in turn passes it back to rank 0. Extending specification 1 leads to:

- rank 0 sends to rank 1
- rank 0 receives from rank 2
- rank 1 receives from rank 0
- rank 1 sends to rank 2
- rank 2 receives from rank 1
- rank 2 sends to rank 0

In pseudocode:

```
loop N times {
   if (rank == 0) {
      MPI_Send to 1
      MPI_Recv from 2
   }
   else if (rank == 1) {
      MPI_Recv from 0
      MPI_Send to 2
   }
   else if (rank == 2) {
      MPI_Recv from 1
      MPI_Send to 0
   }
}
```

Try extending this to four ranks, then to five.

On the other hand, specification 2 extends naturally to three, four... actually, to any number of ranks:

- each rank receives from the previous rank
- each rank sends to the next rank
- rank 0 kickstarts the process by sending the first message and ends the process by receiving one last message

In pseudocode:

```
prev_rank = (rank - 1 + #ranks) % #ranks
next_rank = (rank + 1) % #ranks

if (rank == 0) {
   MPI_Send to next_rank
}

loop N-1 times {
   MPI_Recv from prev_rank
   MPI_Send to next_rank
}

if (rank == 0) {
   MPI_Recv from prev_rank
}
```

It is worth noting that specification 2 is nothing else than a specific case of this generic specification with `#ranks` equal to `2`. In that case, `prev_rank` and `next_rank` are both equal to `(rank + 1) % 2`, i.e., are one and the same rank. Also, `(rank + 1) % 2` and `1 - rank` are the same when rank takes on values that are either `0` or `1`.

I hope you see now the motivation behind not hardcoding specific actions to specific ranks  but rather using locally arithmetic to determine what to do. In your case, every even ping message value is incremented by rank 0 and every odd ping message value by rank 1, but what if you extend it to a ring of ranks? `if (rank == ping_value % #ranks) ping_value++;` kind of does the right thing and works with any number of ranks.

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer. Thanks to you, it helped me to understand the code!!!!!

Comment: To ask one more question, can the meaning of'local' be understood as the same meaning as'regional' used in 'local variable'?

Comment: Local as in not involving knowledge about the MPI program as a whole, just the current rank and its immediate environment.